# Which jQuery attribute do I need to use to find specific text?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to target the `a` tags that contain the html `next &raquo;` and add a class to that tag. I have tried using jQuery's `contains` but obviously it didn't work since I'm here.

```
$('a').contains('next &raquo;').addClass('next');
```

Which attribute do I need to use for this?

Comment: Do you have any other anchor whose HTML content begins with "next"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `:contains()` selector ([ref](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)):

```
$('a:contains("next »")').addClass('next');
```

Comment: Ahh you're right.. we need to render the shortcut.. I'll update my answer - http://jsbin.com/aqanol/2/edit#preview